# Where are the docs for the Chromium Embedded Framework?

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I downloaded and started playing with CEF, but there doesn't seem to be any docs for it. Not even a working wiki… Am I missing something?

Comment: Not an official documentation but I found this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeZvA7MidE0) very useful as an introduction

Answer (score 8):

Most of the documentation is in CEF's [header files](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/d2372c3d1153716f7414b258ed583c235b89b529/include/?at=master). The binary distribution comes with docs generated from those files. It's well documented in terms of amount of content written, but I had a lot of trouble while learning to use it. The project's [Wiki page](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Home) contains a lot of useful content as does the [cefclient sample program](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/d2372c3d1153716f7414b258ed583c235b89b529/tests/cefclient/?at=master).

Comment: my impressions exactly. I guess I'll have to wait until someone more experienced (or with more available time) steps in.

Answer (score 5):

The CEF3 API documentation can be found at http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/
and CEF1 API docuemntation can be found at http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/. These two links can be found on the Chromium Embedded framework (CEF) wiki home page: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Home

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide a link to CEF, so I Googled it, and found the [project's Web site](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), which features a prominent link to their [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/w/list).

The wiki has several pages, but the first one that jumped out at me is the [General Usage](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/GeneralUsage) page that shows how to create a "fully functional embedded browser window using CEF".

So I'm not sure where you were looking, but yes, it looks like you were missing something (grin). The wiki documentation is right there.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself better... Yes, I'd already found that wiki. When I said "working" I meant something with more than a couple of stubs, docs that someone could tweak/enhance vs having to write almost completely, perhaps some reference material. Well, it seems that right now the only info available is that intro.